# Android co pilot generate from comments

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, github-copilot

I tried android kotlin co pilot and it works when I write function name - it proposes to generate outcome.

Also it proposes to finish line of kotlin code.

But it doesn't generate code based in comments in kotlin or comments in XML, like in that medium article.

https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:828/1*4efMJaP9P9jQUqq2jAXQqQ.gif

https://thatrohit.medium.com/power-up-your-android-development-with-github-copilot-957829eadf0f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write a comment and press enter button, and it will work

Comment: Amazing, thanks! also News to wait few seconds

Comment: Comment might be enough, since its just a single line answer with no code.